# "H--- and k-----"

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

**Something has been replaced by question marks. Find what's been replaced and then tell me what the two rows stand for.**

---

[image]

Hint 1:

> The "?'s" are not to be replaced by letters, they're actually to be replaced by.. (yup you guessed it)

Comment: Edit: I changed the puzzle a bit, but this way it's not as messy and more straightforward.  Sorry for inconvenience but hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Ah! Now the title makes sense ...

Comment: I get the title too and I got what the question marks represent and what is next to the numbers but the numbers and the rebus has me stumped atm.

Comment: @PDT I just wanted to hint pbhagevrf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two rows are representing

> The countries…
>  **MEXICO**
>  **LUXEMBOURG**

The Reason

The title:

> I started off by noticing the title had quotation marks around it suggesting a well known phrase and the only well known phrase I could think of that fit the bill, corresponding with the amount of missing letters was **[“HUGS AND KISSES”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugs_and_kisses)** which I then speculated as hinting at Os and Xs and so perhaps too the game [TIC TAC TOE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) as being significant for the solution.

The dashes and question marks:

> Following from the hint it seemed like the cipher being used here was the [MORSE CODE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) since there were dashes and question marks were hinted at to being dots. So we have dashes and dots... I then proceeded to feed the top line of the left series of dashes and question marks into a Morse code decoder and with one configuration of separating the line into chunks it led to XXO something which I felt highly promising due to the title. Then I saw that the other lines could also be separated exclusively into X and Os since x is -..- and o is - - - This led to something promisingly resembling two games of tic tac toe:

> X**X**O
>  O**X**O
>  O**X**

> **O**XX
>  O**O**X
>  XO**O**

> I saw in the left game X wins and in the right O wins. So assuming that I had to somehow graft a couple of words out of the two rows, I assumed that this hinted at the left grid representing the letter X and right representing the letter O!

the picture

> Being the world map made me assume that it is therefore suggesting that **COUNTRIES** are probably the theme for this puzzle.

As a result, the numbers on top of the bars

> I then assumed probably had to represent the **number of letters** to be placed next to the X and O which when taken as a whole **SPELT OUT A COUNTRY**.

So then I thought:

> What countries could fit 2X2O on the top row and 2X3O3 on the bottom?? Well only the countries ME**X**IC**O** and LU**X**EMB**O**URG.

Comment: This answer looks correct but it reads like it is skipping a few steps in the solution. If I were answering this, I'd describe it in terms of *what you do* to the puzzle pieces, not *what they are*.

Comment: @codewarrior0 thanks for the feedback as always, I will try to revise my answer so as to improve it 

Comment: What could be the 11-letter answer to the puzzle in its original state?

Comment: This is it, well done!

Comment: Thanks! So what about the original puzzle out of curiosity it seems drastically different.

Comment: It was 3rd letter of red, 7th letter of blue combined with the world map